# How to build custom plugin to integrate with current theme

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin with a CPT and a CPT template. I would like the template to be able to integrate into any theme it is used with. I thought of calling the 'the_content' hook from my template but I have no idea how to do that as all I can find is calling it from the functions.php file. Please can you tell me how to code this in the CPT template file (like single-CPT.php) or maybe I am heading in the wrong direction so please redirect me. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Basically you want to create a CPT from a plugin and define the "single-CPT" file in the plugin instead of doing it from the theme? Is that correct?

Comment: correct. But in the single-CPT I want it to use not only the theme header and footer but also the theme page html. So I only want to add my custom code in the "the_content" area. Does that make more sense?

Comment: In this case you can use a filter to "the_content"  take a look: http://hookr.io/4.7.4/filters/the_content/
I edited my answer with an example

Comment: thanks, would the single-CPT code look something like this? 
get_header();
your code
get_footer();
? (sorry its such a basic question)

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT:

If you only want to add content to the_content function you can do something like that:

```php
add_filter('the_content', "test_the_content");
function test_the_content($content){
    if(is_singular('test')){
        $content = $content.test_additional_content();
    }
    return $content;
}
function test_additional_content(){
    ob_start(); ?>
    <div class="test">
        Here what you want to display after the_content
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();

}
```

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

If I understood your question correctly, here is how to define the templates of your custom post type in your plugin. This way it will also be possible to overwrite the plugin template from the theme.

The example below is for a CPT called "test", so you have to adapt the code according to the name of your CPT.

```
add_filter('template_include', 'my_plugin_templates');
function my_plugin_templates($template) {
  $post_types = array('test');

  if (is_post_type_archive($post_types) && !file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/archive-test.php')) {
    $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'archive-test.php';
  }

  if (is_singular($post_types) && !file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-test.php')) {
    $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'single-test.php';
  }
  return $template;
}
```

You can also take a look to this repo: https://github.com/zecka/cpt-in-plugin